# Python List not getting appended in fuction

Tags: python, list, function, append

Since variables' values aren't changed inside a function, I first ran a tester for lists. It turns out they do get appended with the new values provided in the function. Here's what I tried

```
def test():
    testlist.append(6)


testlist=[3,4]

print(testlist)

test()

print(testlist)
```

output:-

[3, 4]

[3, 4, 6]

But when I tried this in my actual project it didn't work.
Here's part of the code:-

```
student_name=[]
roll_number=[]

def student_info()
            
            sn=input("Student Name : ")
            student_name.append(sn)

            rn=input("Roll no. : ")
            roll_number.append(rn)
```

the student_info() runs as many times as there are students, which is also a variable.

Each time, the list appends a value for each student. All these values will later be extracted whenever needed using the index number. But when I try to call a list value it's always the first value of the list that comes. So the list is not being appended?

```
def print_card():
        for p in range(0,no_of_classes,1):
            for l in range(0,class_strength,1):
           
                print("Student Name:",student_name[l],x*50,"Roll No:",roll_number[l])
```

(please ignore the unnecessarily complex formatting part)

```
#This is the main part of the code.

for j in range (no_of_classes):
    
    class_=input("Class name")
    print("Class strength of ",class_)
    class_strength=int(input())
    
    for i in range (class_strength):
        student_info()
print_card()
```

Here's the minimum reproducible program

```
student_name=[]
roll_number=[]

def student_info():
            
            sn=input("Student Name : ")
            student_name.append(sn)

            rn=input("Roll no. : ")
            roll_number.append(rn)
            
def print_card():
        for p in range(0,no_of_classes,1):
            for l in range(0,class_strength,1):
                x=' '
                print('\n')
                print("Student Name:",student_name[l],x*50,"Roll No:",roll_number[l])

no_of_classes=2
class_strength=1

for j in range (0,no_of_classes):
    
    for i in range (0,class_strength):
        student_info()
        
        
print_card()
```

The card gets created for the first class but for the next class, the same output comes. Why is this happening?

Expected output vs Actual output

(say for 2 students)

```
                                      kode skool                                     
Student Name: 1                                                    Roll No: 1
Class: 1                                                           Section: 1
Address    1
           1


City:  1                                                        Pin Code: 1
Guardian's Phone Number 1


                                      kode skool                                        
Student Name: 2                                                    Roll No: 2
Class: 2                                                           Section: 2
Address    2
           2


City: 2                                                     Pin Code: 2
Guardian's Phone Number 2



-------------------------------------------------------------------



                                      kode skool  
Student Name: 1                                                    Roll No: 1
Class: 1                                                           Section: 1
Address    1
           1


City:  1                                                        Pin Code: 1
Guardian's Phone Number 1





                                      kode skool  
Student Name: 1                                                    Roll No: 1
Class: 1                                                           Section: 1
Address    1
           1


City:  1                                                        Pin Code: 1
Guardian's Phone Number 1
```

Comment: `when I try to call a list value it's always the first index value that comes` is not clear. I can't make heads or tails of it at all honestly. Please show an example output versus what you expect the output to be. Also, your example is not a [mre], as you haven't defined `i`, `new_line`, `no_of_classes`, or `class_strength`, and you said `ignore unnecessarily complex formatting part` which indicates that you could remove that and still have it be an example of the issue.

Comment: sorry for making the question so vague. By the first index value, I mean the first value of the list.

Comment: Okay cool, let me know when you take care of the other things I mentioned so that I can try helping you.

Comment: it is part of the for loop, which I am using to make the student_info() run a couple of times. [ for i in range (1,class_strength) ] is the exact line

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]; the full output isn't necessary to demonstrate whether a list is being updated or not. The function `student_info` looks fine, but you aren't showing how or where you *call* the function, nor how (or if) the values used in `range` relate to the two lists you want to update.

Comment: @Natru external links to code aren't accepted here. Your code needs to go into the post itself. Also there's no point in sharing the full code if your issue can be solved via a [mre].

Comment: @RandomDavis Understood i will try making it

Comment: @RandomDavis I've edited it to make it clearer. Is there anything else I can do it make my post better?

Comment: @Natru please read the [mre] page. I can't just copy your code, paste it into an IDE and run it. Anyone should be able to. Help us out and we can help you.

Comment: I think problem is because you create flat lists with all students but you should create nested list `[ [..., ...], [..., ...] ]`  - every `class_` as sublist. And then you could use `students[class_number][student_number]` to get correct value. With flat list you have to calculate `students[ class_number*class_strength + student_number ]` or even worst `students[ class_1_strength + class_2_strength + ... + student_number ]` because every class may have different `strength`

Comment: @RandomDavis I've added a minimal reproducible example now

Comment: Okay thank you. So, if `class_strength` is `1`, and you have `for l in range(0,class_strength,1)`, that means that `l` will only ever be `0` (because range is not inclusive, meaning a range of 0 to 1 will just contain 0). So, while `student_name` and `roll_number` _do_ have more than one item, you're only ever _getting_ the first item. Why are you doing that?

Comment: so i should add +1 to the stop value, right?

Comment: your mind problem is that you have nested `for`-loops but you keep data in `flat list` but you should keep in `nested lists`. Adding `+1` can't resove this problem. You should keep every `class` as sublist. OR you should use single for-loop to display all students but it this way you can't get class number. It would need to keep class number and other information together with student  name - ie. as tuple `(student name, class_number, roll_number, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your problem is you keep all students on one flat list

```
students = [name1, name2, name3, ...]
```

so later it makes problem to get correctly data for second class.

You use indexes `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. to get students from second class but it would need

```
[class_1_strength + 0], [class_1_strength + 1], etc.
```

And to get students from third class you would need

```
[class_1_strength + class_2_strength + 0], [class_1_strength + class_2_strength + 1], etc.
```

so it makes big problem.

It would be much simpler if you will keep every class as sublist

```
school = [
    [name1, name2, name3, ...], # class 1
    [name1, name2, name3, ...], # class 2
    # etc.
]
```

or as dictionary:

```
school = {
    'class_1_name': [name1, name2, name3, ...], # class 1
    'class_2_name': [name1, name2, name3, ...], # class 2
    # etc.
}
```

Frankly, it would be good to keep all values together:

```
school = [
    [ (name1, roll_number, ...),  (name2, roll_number, ...), ...], # class 1
    [ (name1, roll_number, ...),  (name2, roll_number, ...), ...], # class 2
    # etc.
]
```

---

Minimal working example.

I use `random`, `string` only to create some data for test - so I don't have to use `input()`.

I use `random.seed(0)` to get always the same data - so I can compare them with previous execution.

```
import random
import string

random.seed(0)

def generate_random_name(lenght=5):
    return "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=lenght))

def get_student_info():
    
    #student_name = input("Student Name : ")
    #roll_number  = input("Roll no. : ")

    student_name = generate_random_name()
    roll_number  = 1

    return student_name, roll_number
    
def print_card():
    for class_number, class_students in enumerate(school, 1):
        print('--- class:', class_number, '---\n')
        for item in class_students:
            student_name, roll_number, class_number = item

            print(f"Student Name: {student_name:}")
            print(f"Roll No: {roll_number}")
            print(f"Class: {class_number}")
            print()
        
# --- main ---

school = []

no_of_classes = 2
class_strength = 3

for class_number in range(1, no_of_classes+1):

    class_students = [] # list for all students in one clas

    for student_number in range(1, class_strength+1):

        student_name, roll_number = get_student_info()

        # all information about one student        
        item = [student_name, student_number, class_number]

        class_students.append(item)

    school.append(class_students)
        
print_card()
```

Result:

```
--- class: 1 ---

Student Name: VTKGN
Roll No: 1
Class: 1

Student Name: KUHMP
Roll No: 2
Class: 1

Student Name: XNHTQ
Roll No: 3
Class: 1

--- class: 2 ---

Student Name: GXZVX
Roll No: 1
Class: 2

Student Name: ISXRM
Roll No: 2
Class: 2

Student Name: CLPXZ
Roll No: 3
Class: 2
```